# How to find what custom config is used by iptables?

Tags: centos, iptables

I need to open the custom iptables config, and change old IP address to new. How I can find what custom config is used by iptables?

Comment: You mean `iptables -vL` or `iptables -t nat -vL`?

Comment: I mean iptables -vL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` comes with the utilities which might be useful to update `iptables` configuration safely: `iptables-save`,`iptables-restore`, `iptables-apply`.

To temporarily change and test *running* configuration, you could do like this:

```
$ sudo iptables-save > rules.v4
$ vi rules.v4
$ sudo iptables-restore < rules.v4
```

If you want to change configuration on remote servers, using `iptables-apply` instead of `iptables-restore` would be recommended.

Some Linux distributions integrate those utilities to keep *permanent* settings and statistics which automatically get restored across reboots.  So you'd better look for your distro's way and follow it.

For example [RHEL6 document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables.html) mentions `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.  I'm not sure about `firewalld` introduced in RHEL7/CentOS7.  For Debian based systems you might want to install [iptables-persistent](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/iptables-persistent).